# E/launcher - invalid session id. Getting the error when running cucumber protractor framework. How can i resolve it and run multiple feature files?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

1. Here is the protractor configuration js file
2. I am getting the error when running more than one spec file
3. The error it gives me is invalid session id

```
        const Reporter = require("../support/reporter");

        exports.config = {

           capabilities: {
              browserName: process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || "chrome"
           },
           waitForAngularEnabled: true,
           useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
           framework: "custom",
           frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
           specs: ["../features/*.feature"],

           onPrepare: function () {
             browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
             browser.manage().window().maximize();
             require('babel-register');
           },

           cucumberOpts: {
              strict: true,
              format: 'json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json',
              require: ["../stepDefinitions/*.js", "../support/*.js"],
              tags: "@CucumberScenario"
           },
           onComplete: function () {
              Reporter.createHTMLReport();
           }
        };
```

Error message is as below:

```
E/launcher - invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: '******', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '********', ip: '********', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown


[11:40:32] E/launcher - WebDriverError: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: '*******', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '*******', ip: '**********', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: Can you put the error here for better clarity? I think the session is not being created because your chrome version is not compatible. Are you running webdriver-manager update before running your tests? Which version of chrome is the tests running? There is too little information provided to answer this question.

Comment: Hi @Sankalan Parajuli -  The above is the error i get when running 2 feature files. Yes i did the webdriver manager update before running the tests.

Comment: This is the git repo i am using and made few updates on the latest versions of protractor and other dev dependencies.

Comment: Git repo - https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-allure

Comment: Error message added in the description

Comment: Please rewrite the question to be specific, don't just paste "Help, got this error" questions. S.O. is for helping you to get answers to questions, not "Help me with my code, please".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with cucumber so this error might be completely different than what I am guessing. You should try this once:

Add the following to your package.json scripts section and then run `npm run test` to compile the typescript and then fix update the webdriver chrome version. If your code is in javascript, remove the `npm run tsc` from pretest.

```
 "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.conf.js",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc && npm run webdriver-update",
    "test": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor/compiled-js-files/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e": "npm run tsc && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor/compiled-js-files/protractor.conf.js",
    "grid": "sh run-grid.sh && npm run tsc && npm run e2e",
    "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0 --chrome --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.97",
    "lighthouse": "./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --verbose -t=lighthouse",
    "lighthouse-reports": "./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --verbose -t=lighthouse && node ./lighthouse/db.js"
  }
```

This will allow you to download the last known good configuration (known to me) of chrome. You will need to keep maintaining this so that you don't use an outdated chrome. The reason for this error is that webdriver-manager update takes the latest beta version of chrome release and that release is not made for automation testing. Because of which a session is not created when you run your tests.

Also try adding the following in your capabilities:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox" , "--window-size=1440,960"]
        },
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Sankalan Parajuli...I have added the scripts in my package.json. I am running from javascript and not typescript and so i have removed the typescript commands. When i type -  npm run webdriver-update , I get the error as - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I do not need a headless run and my current chrome version is 78.0.3904.97. I have deleted the update folder of google and has stopped the update.

Comment: I am assuming your node modules are not in the root directory where your package.json and protractor configuration files are. You can change the path to your  npm package of protractor's webdriver-manager. Try using absolute path to that file according to your project's folder structure.

Comment: Yeah i think you are right. I will try that Sankalan. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: Sure. A npm clean fixed the root directory issues -  npm install npm-clean -g